# Training a model for fall detection

Tags: machine-learning

My parents are elderly and a fall is a BIG DEAL.  I'm pretty good at coding and such.  So I thought I'd use some fall datasets and plug them into a machine learning system.  As you can see from this statement, I am new to machine learning.  How should I start getting my first model?  Literature has pointed me to trying a decision tree model as better than KNN...do I pick up TensorFlow and start plying a model with datasets, or how would you start?  Thank you and I apologize for my noob question.

Comment: Interesting project. However, it is important to know how your data look like to get an idea of what a good approach could be.

Comment: I'm not sure that you have a good case for using ML: in order to train a good model you would need data containing a number of observations (probably from some sensors, maybe cameras?) labeled with whether a fall occurred or not. You probably don't want your parents to fall repeatedly just to collect some training data!

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  I plan to start with existing datasets, like this one I found: sistemic.udea.edu.co/en/investigacion/proyectos/english-falls .  I believe there was a project with NIH, which I thought as a taxpayer I should be able to get to the data?  Anyways, advice always appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of such a dataset, but I would suggest you to borrow ideas from mobile phone accelerometer projects. e.g.  the links below can be a good inspiration.

To proceed, I would record their daily movement and generate the normal movement thresholds (probably you could just use an off the shelf android phone utilizing its motion sensor).

Based on the collected dataset, you will define what are the normal movements (e.g. you can start with fixed rules). Later you dynamically adjust based on the feedback from your parents.

Concerning machine learning algorithms, After you collect high dimensional data for long enough time you can proceed with the algorithms you mentioned above.

(e.g. setting it as a classification algorithm)

```
(speed, time, pt1, pt2, ...) -> fall
(speed, time, pt1, pt2, ...) -> no_fall
```

good luck!

[1] step detection https://github.com/danielmurray/adaptiv

[2] sensors overview https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview

Comment: Thank you.  I will look at your links.  I'm going to start with these datasets: http://sistemic.udea.edu.co/en/investigacion/proyectos/english-falls/  .  Any advice appreciated!  Again, much thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am in a similar situation, trying to build and train a fall detection system for a family member.  Apple watch is not an option in my case.

I ran across this data set that may help you.  It appears to be raw data from a Samsung Galaxy phone
https://bmi.teicrete.gr/en/the-mobifall-and-mobiact-datasets-2/

From the site:  "MobiAct is a publicly available dataset which includes data from a smartphone when participants are performing different types of activities and a range of falls"

Hope this helps